# 'TemplateDoesNotExist' error with creating Sitemap for Django app

Tags: django, sitemap

I followed the sitemap activation steps on the django site but i keep getting a 'TemplateDoesNotExist' error. Maybe i am misunderstanding, but isn't genericview supposed to generate the page?

```
########### url.py #############################3

.........
from django.contrib.sitemaps import FlatPageSitemap, GenericSitemap
........
........
info_dict = {
'queryset': Bookmark.objects.all(),
'date_field': 'added'
}
sitemaps = {
'bookmarks': GenericSitemap(info_dict, changefreq = 'never', priority=0.6),
}
urlpatterns = patterns('',
.............
url(r'^$', 'microblogging.views.public', name="home"),
(r'^sitemap.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
.............
)
if settings.SERVE_MEDIA:
urlpatterns += patterns('',
(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'misc.views.serve')
)



############# error #############################

TemplateDoesNotExist at /sitemap.xml

sitemap.xml

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/sitemap.xml
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:

sitemap.xml

Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template_source, line 73
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python2.5
Python Version: 2.5.4
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is because it's not finding the default templates.

Make sure `'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source'` is in your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting, and also make sure that `'django.contrib.sitemaps'` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Yes, they are both in my settings file.

Comment: Ahh! because i had setup settings.py/local_settings.py for dev/production , i forgot to add it to local_settings.py

Answer (score 6):

deprecated, latest is: 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',

Answer (score 5):

You can try removing `django.contrib.sites` from the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Just add the `django.contrib.sitemaps`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` any more.